# When to and not to specify "window." prefix for window property and methods

Tags: javascript

Some properties and methods are consistently prefixed with `window.` while others are not.

For example, `document` and `setTimeout()` are almost never used with `window.` prefix. On the other hand, `window.location` and `window.open()` are very often used with the prefix.

I know that they essentially refer to the same thing, and that without `window.`, the name can be shadowed by the same name in the inner scope. I'm not asking about grammatical difference, but the reason for this convention. With this level of consistency, I am expecting that there is a reason for it, and I want to know why.

Members almost always found without prefix:

- `document`
- `console`
- `setTimeout()`
- `alert()`
- `fetch()`

with prefix:

- `window.location`
- `window.onload`
- `window.open()`

Comment: My guess is that `location`, `onload` and `open` are too generic to be used without attaching to something else. Attaching them will make your code more readable. However, and the case of `setTimeout` and the others, no benefit is added if you do attach them to `window`.

Comment: Most can be blamed on old w3schools docs, but it's always `window.URL` too for some reason, the newest member of the redundant `window.` family of JS traditions. It's driven me nuts for years; I mockingly ask "why not use `window.window.URL`?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a question relates to the scopes of Javascript.

The scopes are like this

```
----------foo------------
|       var location    |
|                       | 
|     ------bar---------------
|     |   window.location    |
|     |                      |
|     |           -------baz----------
|     |           |  location = ''   |
|     |           |                  |
|     |           --------------------
|     |-----------------------|
|------------------------|
```

`foo, bar and baz` are all functions(or blocks for `const` and `let`), so If I want to access global(window for example) things(property or method), I need to use `window.xxx`, otherwise, a user-defined thing may be referenced, for example the `location` defined in `foo` function.

**For these members:**

Members almost always found without prefix:

```
document
console
setTimeout()
alert()
fetch()
```

Because:

1. We treat them as function or constant(`document`)
2. We don't mutate anything, we just call a function or read something.

with prefix:

```
window.location
window.onload
window.open()
```

Because:

1. We do mutate something.
2. We treat them as object properties.
3. More descriptive, compare `window.open` vs `open`, **open what? WINDOW!! The code said so.**

### Another reason

The current scope may give you a custom method defined in `window`, AKA `shadowing`, you may want to use that.

```
function foo () {
  function alert (sth) {
    console.log(`alert:${sth}`)
    window.alert(sth)
  }
  alert('I am Carebear.')
}

foo()
```

Imagine a library or your friends defined a custom `alert` which is 100% compatible with the `window.alert`. Calling alert without window can leverage it.